# Bootstrap-angular-ui modal on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-angular-ui-modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for a site I am working on. The code I am using to open the modal

```
$modal.open(
    {
        templateUrl: '/home/template',
        controller: myCtrl,
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything is working fine. But I need to find a way to execute some code after modal is loaded. I tried different things but can't make them work. Some of things I tried

In template I did

```
<script>
    document.onload = function () {
        console.log('opened');
    };
</script>
```

I also found there is a promise for the angular modal object named openned. I tried to

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function(){console.log('hello')});
```

not working either. I can use some help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely not a good solution, but at least worked for me. I just added a timeout before executing the desired function,

```
modalInstance.opened.then(
    $timeout(function() {
            console.log('hello');
        }, delay));
```

Answer (score 5):

UI-bootstraps modal has a `result` resolve.

> "opened" - a promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after
>   downloading content's template and resolving all variables

or

Use ng-init. Create a div inside your template file:

```
<div ng-init="func()"></div>
```

Comment: tried `opened` promise. gets called before modal is loaded. that is why jquery binding codes not working. and about ng-init - `The only appropriate use of ngInit for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`

Comment: And how to tell to the controller to init on create ? it's the question here. Why ng-init="mycontroller.init()" is evil ?

Answer (score 3):

[Since version 0.13.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/99af5f8a369b13b018ec1e592d82a1a140cbb6bb), there's a `rendered` promise you can use.

> `rendered` *(Type: `promise`)* - Is resolved when a modal is rendered.

Example:

```
this.modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
    console.log("modal is rendered");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to do something after the DOM is loaded, it's best to do that sort of thing inside a directive.  See here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom

You could mark your modal body (or something inside the modal) with your directive attribute, then create the directive like so:

```
App.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                // stuff to do after DOM load here
            });
        }

        return {
             link: link
        };
    });
```