# Angular ui Open Modal Automatically on load page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

angular-ui-modal][1](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for create my site and I want to show my modal automatically when the user enter in my webpage. With `ng-click` is easy , I have this code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
$scope.openModal = function(data) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modals/register.html',
    resolve: {
      data: function() {
        return data === null ? {} : data;
      }
    }
  });
};
}]);
```

But I do not know how trigger the modal when load page.
Any help? Please

Comment: Just call the same code outside of the scope function. Also `$modal` is an old version so you may want to consider upgrading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap-angular-ui modal on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657323/bootstrap-angular-ui-modal-on-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call the function when the controller is loaded:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.openModal = function(data) {
    $scope.blurred  = "blurredopen";
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modals/register.html',
      resolve: {
        data: function() {
          return data === null ? {} : data;
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.openModal(); // <-- Call it
}]);
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3v58n3a/)

Comment: Added a JSFiddle demo. Be sure you call `$scope.openModal()` **after** declaring the function.

Comment: other question @Mistalis , if i want the modal appears after x seconds? Thanks for your help

Comment: use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), if you've found Mistalis's answer helpful then please accept or at least upvote it.

Comment: Thanks @svarog, how i must use $timeout?

Comment: yes works fine with timeout but i have a hard problem, cant add a contoller to modal